# Are scala.util.automata, scala.util.regexp, and scala.util.grammar really needed?

Tags: scala

These package exist for a long time as far as I know.  However, I have not ever seen their realistic usage.  And it seems that these packages are immature and no longer maintained.  If yes, why these packages exist now ?

Answer (score 4):

The package `automata` is used by `scala.xml.dtd`, and `regexp` is used by `automata`. As for `grammar`, I couldn't find any use of it and, perhaps, it could be removed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I understood that automata ( and regex ) is used in scala standard library.  If its usage are internal, I think that these packages should not be public API.  However, for example, it seems that scala.xml.dtd.DFAContentModel publish scala.util.automata.DetWordAutom.